# Stubbing static methods in Mockito 2 throws InvalidUseOfMatchersException

Tags: java, mockito, powermock

I have a class where I'm using Powermock + Mockito to suppress a static method in a utility class. It works fine with Powermock 1.6.2 and Mockito 1.10.19, but I've been tasked with moving to Java 10 (JRE: we're still compiling with Java 8) and so I've moved to Powermock 2 (currently in beta) and Mockito 2.16.1. Now, I consistently get `org.mockito.exceptions.misusing.InvalidUseOfMatchersException: 
Misplaced or misused argument matcher detected here`.

A simple example, MyMockito.java:

```
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.powermock.core.classloader.annotations.PrepareForTest;
import org.powermock.modules.junit4.PowerMockRunner;

import java.lang.reflect.Method;

import static org.mockito.Mockito.any;
import static org.powermock.api.mockito.PowerMockito.spy;
import static org.powermock.api.mockito.PowerMockito.when;
import static org.powermock.api.support.membermodification.MemberMatcher.method;
import static org.powermock.api.support.membermodification.MemberModifier.suppress;

@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest(StringMeasurer.class)
public class MyMockito {
    @Test
    public void testSuppressMethod() throws Exception {
        spy(StringMeasurer.class);
        Method measure = method(StringMeasurer.class, "measure", String.class);
        suppress(measure);
        when(StringMeasurer.class, measure)
                .withArguments(any(String.class))
                .thenReturn(10);
        System.out.println(StringMeasurer.measure("Hello"));
    }
```

And StringMeasurer.java:

```
    public class StringMeasurer {
        private StringMeasurer() {}
        public static int measure(String s) {
            return s.length();
        }
    }
}
```

I'm assuming that either there have been some changes to how matchers can be used to match arguments in stubbed static methods, or else this should *never* have worked and somehow got through in Mockito 2 (or possibly this is a bug in the Powermock beta). Can anyone provide me some insight into what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Looks like you have the wrong class in your `@PrepareForTest` annotation. You're not doing anything with `String`

Comment: True. But that doesn't seem to be the source of the problem (assuming I'm using `@PrepareForTest` correctly now).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Working solution for PowerMock `2.0.0-beta.5`:

```java
import static org.mockito.ArgumentMatchers.any;
import static org.powermock.api.mockito.PowerMockito.when;

import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.powermock.api.mockito.PowerMockito;
import org.powermock.core.classloader.annotations.PrepareForTest;
import org.powermock.modules.junit4.PowerMockRunner;

@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest(StringMeasurer.class)
public class MyMockito {
    @Test
    public void testSuppressMethod() throws Exception {
        PowerMockito.mockStatic(StringMeasurer.class);
        when(StringMeasurer.measure(any(String.class))).thenReturn(10);
        System.out.println(StringMeasurer.measure("Hello"));
    }
}
```

More details can be found in the official PowerMock documentation: [Mocking Static Method](https://github.com/powermock/powermock/wiki/Mockito#mocking-static-method)

Comment: This helped me a lot, but I subsequently realised that I also need to use partial mocking in some cases. This answer led me to a partial mocking solution for that which I'll post as a second answer.

Answer (score 0):

The question uses the `PowerMockito.spy()` method, which is required for partial mocking, although the example given only has one static method, so that's not necessary here. Here's a working solution that uses partial mocking for an extended example:

MyMockito.java:

```
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.powermock.core.classloader.annotations.PrepareForTest;
import org.powermock.modules.junit4.PowerMockRunner;

import java.lang.reflect.Method;
import java.util.List;

import static junit.framework.Assert.assertEquals;
import static org.mockito.Mockito.*;
import static org.powermock.api.support.membermodification.MemberMatcher.method;
import static org.powermock.api.mockito.PowerMockito.doReturn;
import static org.powermock.api.mockito.PowerMockito.spy;

@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest(StringMeasurer.class)
public class MyMockito {
    @Test
    public void testSuppressMethod() throws Exception {
        spy(StringMeasurer.class);
        Method measure = method(StringMeasurer.class, "measure", String.class);
        doReturn(10).when(StringMeasurer.class, measure)
                .withArguments(any(String.class));
        System.out.println(StringMeasurer.measure("Hello"));
        List<String> dummy = StringMeasurer.dummy(5);
        assertEquals(5, dummy.size());
        dummy.forEach(System.out::println);
    }
}
```

And StringMeasurer.java:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class StringMeasurer {
    private StringMeasurer() {}
    public static int measure(String s) {
        return s.length();
    }
    public static List<String> dummy(int size) {
        List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
            list.add("" + i);
        }
        return list;
    }
}
```

Note that, in this case, the accepted solution would mock the `StringMeasurer.dummy()` method as well, returning an empty list, and the test would fail on the `assertEquals()`.